# Install printer Canon MP280 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, printing, 20.04, canon, libtiff

I am trying to install my Canon MP280 printer to my recently upgraded Ubuntu focal 20.04.  This printer worked out-of-the-box with Ubuntu 18.04 on same hardware (HP Folio 1040), so I am surprised to find it does not work quite so well.

I've tried two paths:

1. *system-config-printer*:  This leads me to either install a generic
   text-only driver, or a list of non-matching Canon printers.  Either way I cannot actually print anything.
2. *install proprietary driver* as described [here](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2018/06/28/printer-canon-mp280-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-how-to-download-install/).  This ultimately fails due to a dependency to an arcane version of [libtiff4](https://medium.com/@konpat/installing-canon-mp280-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04-8b15d11d969) whereas libtiff5 is the only available on 20.04.

Did Ubuntu leave my printer behind?

[image: install printer]

[image: printer detected]

[image: gutenberg driver recommended]

[image: list of supported printers]

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2438256

Comment: sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint && system-config-printer == success! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Comment: For any Canon printer see this answer (also works for Ubuntu 20.04):
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261887/canon-g1010-driver-installation-on-ubuntu-20-04/1294113#1294113

Answer (score 10):

To resolve:

```
sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint
system-config-printer
```

Comment: works on 20.04 and 21.10

Comment: and works on 22.04  with MP270
i still can't fathom why it stopped working out-of-the-box on since 20.04

Answer (score 1):

There is a PPA for Canon printer drivers. MP280 is listed in [this Ubuntu Handbook article](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/10/canon-ij-printer-scangear-mp-drivers-ubuntu-18-04-18-10/) among devices covered. This worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cnijfilter2 scangearmp2 cndrvcups-utility
```

After this, you should be able to use `apt search mp280` (replace `mp280` as needed for other devices) to find the correct driver, or install Synaptic Package Manager (`sudo apt install synaptic`) for a nice GUI search.

Comment: cndrvcups-utility does not exist in that repo. 
apt search mp280 shows nothing

Comment: This worked for mp495, thank you!

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me when trying to set up a Canon MG2200 series printer on Ubuntu 20.04. I originally installed the driver from the manufacturer and had been stuck with a printer that CUPS said was completing print jobs successfully, but wasn't responding.