# Looking for an Ubuntu USB driver for a Canon MG5350 printer

Tags: usb, 20.04, acer, canon

I have tried to find a driver which works for my Canon MG5350 on Ubuntu 20.04LTS on my *Acer Aspire One* notebook, but no luck so far.

How do I find one and install it?

Answer (score 3):

Thierry Ordissimo has a PPA for cannon drivers the official drivers of Canon printers and multifunction devices, [cannon printer and scanner ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Ethierry-f/+archive/ubuntu/fork-michael-gruz) made  included versions 2.20 and newer, into PPA. There’s also sane backend for some scanners.

Supported devices in the repository:

```
bjf900, bjf9000
bjs300, bjs500
e400, e500, e510, e560, e600, e610
i250, i255
ip90, ip100, ip1800, ip1900, ip2200, ip2500, ip2600, ip2700, ip2800, ip3300, ip3500, ip3600, ip4200, ip4300, ip4500, ip4600, ip4700, ip4800, ip4900, ip6600d, ip7200, ip7500, ip8700
ix6500, ix6700, ix6800
mg2100, mg2200, mg2400, mg2500, mg3100, mg3200, mg3500, mg4100, mg4200, mg5100, mg5200, mg5300, mg5400, mg5500, mg6100, mg6200, mg6300, mg6400, mg6500, mg7100, mg8100, mg8200.
mp140, mp160, mp190, mp210, mp230, mp240, mp250, mp270, mp280, mp490, mp495, mp500, mp510, mp520, mp540, mp550, mp560, mp600, mp610, mp630, mp640
mx320, mx330, mx340, mx350, mx360, mx370, mx390, mx410, mx420, mx430, mx450, mx470, mx510, mx520, mx530, mx710, mx720, mx860, mx870, mx880, mx890, mx920.
p200
pixmaip1000, pixmaip1500
pixus550i, pixus560i, pixus850i, pixus860i, pixus950i, pixus990i
pixusip3100, pixusip4100, pixusip8600
```

and so on

add the ppa, update and install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cnijfilter2 scangearmp2 cndrvcups-utility
```

Jim of ubuntuhandbook has [a detailed explanation](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/10/canon-ij-printer-scangear-mp-drivers-ubuntu-18-04-18-10/) you can just adjust to Ubuntu 20.04.

[A similar answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1241123/673145) for another canon printer suggests:

> ```
> sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint
> system-config-printer
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful

Comment: cndrvcups-utility doesn't exist anymore, at least not for 20.04

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install the published drivers from Canon's own website, libtiff4 and libpng12 dependencies will fail nowadays. But here's a flow that will resolve it that I use myself for the MX410. You can probably adjust it for the MG5350.

Assuming these are the drivers:
https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg5350.html?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:13-863341&os=linux%20%2864-bit%29&language=en

Or just pull the .deb package:
wget https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/4/0100003954/01/cnijfilter-mg5300series-3.60-1-deb.tar.gz

Script itself is fairly self explanatory and tested for MX410. Manually patch for using the MG5300 .deb file

---

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install libpng12-0

# pull old multiarch-support and tiff4 
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb

# install dependencies
sudo dpkg -i multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb

# pull canon europe linux drivers
wget https://files.canon-europe.com/files/soft40865/Software/Linux%20IJ%20Printer%20Driver%20MX410.tar

#install mx410 drivers
tar xvf Linux\ IJ\ Printer\ Driver\ MX410.tar
tar zxvf cnijfilter-mx410series-3.50-1-deb.tar.gz
cd cnijfilter-mx410series-3.50-1-deb
sudo ./install.sh
cd ..

# Remove remove after installed
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12
```