# Canon ip7210 Drivers installation

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

How to install a Canon IP7210 on a 20.04 having .deb packages problems dependencies manually?.

Context:

```
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de cnijfilter-ip7200series: cnijfilter-ip7200series depende de `libpng12-0` (>= 1.2.8rel); sin embargo:
El paquete `libpng12-0` no está instalado.
cnijfilter-ip7200series depende de `libtiff4`; sin embargo:
El paquete `libtiff4` no está instalado.
```

Answer (score 1):

It was a question, until find this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247201/looking-for-an-ubuntu-usb-driver-for-a-canon-mg5350-printer?answertab=votes) and making these steps:

1. [Download](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0100004655/01/cnijfilter-ip7200series-3.80-1-deb.tar.gz) the .tar.gz printer driver's
2. [Download](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb) the old multiarch support (x64)
3. [Download](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb) the corresponding tiff lib (x64) requested (located in universe)
4. Resolve `libpng12-0` package dependency (searched and located):

> `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12`
> `$ sudo apt-get update`

Then, proceed:

> `$ sudo dpkg -i multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb`
> `$ sudo dpkg -i libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb`
> `$ sudo apt-get install libpng12-0`

Lastly we can run the install.sh inside printer drivers file (located inside uncompressed folder)

> `cnijfilter-ip7200series-3.80-1-deb$ sudo ./install.sh`

Follow installation's guide steps to get printer working.

Comment: FYI - there a special Canon-related [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~thierry-f/+archive/ubuntu/fork-michael-gruz?field.series_filter=focal) which has needed [deb-packages](https://launchpad.net/~thierry-f/+archive/ubuntu/fork-michael-gruz/+packages?field.name_filter=cnijfilter&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=focal).

Comment: these model aren't supported by muchael-gruz's PPA. i tried.

Comment: I understood, just tried to save some of your time :) It is great that you have found a solution.

Comment: hope this save some other's time too!