# Printer prints only Unrecoverable error on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing

When I try to print ODT or PDF or something else, the printer prints only:
`unrecoverable error: rangecheck in .putdeviceprops` and error message in `/var/log/cups/error_log` is:

```
E [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the /var/log/cups/error_log file for details.
```

Log from: `cat /var/log/cups/error_log`:

```
E [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the /var/log/cups/error_log file for details.
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] The following messages were recorded from 11:59:13 to 11:59:25
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Applying default options...
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Adding start banner page "none".
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Adding end banner page "none".
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] File of type application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner queued by "tomas".
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] hold_until=0
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Queued on "Photosmart-B110" by "tomas".
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] time-at-processing=1640084353
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] 3 filters for job:
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] bannertopdf (application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner to application/pdf, cost 32)
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] pdftopdf (application/pdf to application/vnd.cups-pdf, cost 66)
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] foomatic-rip (application/vnd.cups-pdf to printer/Photosmart-B110, cost 0)
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] job-sheets=none,none
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] argv[0]="Photosmart-B110"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] argv[1]="496"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] argv[2]="tomas"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] argv[3]="Testovací stránka"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] argv[4]="1"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] argv[5]="job-uuid=urn:uuid:ed884279-c10e-3377-5f28-7d6ee73b5fb7 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1640084353 time-at-processing=1640084353"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00496-001"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[4]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[8]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@tomas-Dell-5590"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.3.1"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[13]="USER=root"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[14]="CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[15]="CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[16]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[17]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[18]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[19]="LANG=cs_CZ.UTF-8"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[20]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/Photosmart-B110.ppd"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[21]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[22]="CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[23]="DEVICE_URI=socket://192.168.0.99:9100"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[24]="PRINTER_INFO=Photosmart B110c"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[25]="PRINTER_LOCATION="
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[26]="PRINTER=Photosmart-B110"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[27]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[28]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[29]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-pdf"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] envp[30]="AUTH_I****"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf (PID 33676)
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 33677)
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/foomatic-rip (PID 33680)
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/socket (PID 33681)
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Looking up \"192.168.0.99\"...
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] 192.168.0.99=192.168.0.99
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] pdftopdf: Last filter determined by the PPD: foomatic-rip; FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE: application/vnd.cups-pdf => pdftopdf will log pages in page_log.
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-Photosmart-B110)
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_Photosmart_B110
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Calling org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device.Get(ProfilingInhibitors)
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] PDF template file doesn\'t have form. It\'s okay.
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] \'CM Color Calibration\' Mode in SPOOLER-LESS: Off
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Getting input from file 
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] foomatic-rip version 1.27.4 running...
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Parsing PPD file ...
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Added option ColorSpace
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Added option PageSize
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Added option ImageableArea
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Added option PaperDimension
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Added option ColorMode
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Added option Quality
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Added option RenderType
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Added option Font
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Parameter Summary
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] -----------------
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Spooler: cups
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Printer: Photosmart-B110
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Shell: /bin/sh
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] PPD file: /etc/cups/ppd/Photosmart-B110.ppd
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] ATTR file: 
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Printer model: HP PhotoSmart P100 Foomatic/pjxl300
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Job title: Testovací stránka
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] File(s) to be printed:
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] <STDIN>
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Ghostscript extra search path (\'GS_LIB\'): /usr/share/cups/fonts
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Printing system options:
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Pondering option \'job-uuid=urn:uuid:ed884279-c10e-3377-5f28-7d6ee73b5fb7\'
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Unknown option job-uuid=urn:uuid:ed884279-c10e-3377-5f28-7d6ee73b5fb7.
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Pondering option \'job-originating-host-name=localhost\'
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Unknown option job-originating-host-name=localhost.
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Pondering option \'date-time-at-creation=\'
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Unknown option date-time-at-creation=.
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Pondering option \'date-time-at-processing=\'
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Unknown option date-time-at-processing=.
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Pondering option \'time-at-creation=1640084353\'
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Unknown option time-at-creation=1640084353.
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Pondering option \'time-at-processing=1640084353\'
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Unknown option time-at-processing=1640084353.
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] CM Color Calibration Mode in CUPS: Off
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Options from the PPD file:
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] ================================================
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] File: <STDIN>
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] ================================================
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] PID 33676 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf) exited with no errors.
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] PDF interactive form and annotation flattening done via QPDF
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] PAGE: 1 1
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Filetype: PDF
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Storing temporary files in /tmp
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] PID 33677 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] hrDeviceDesc=\"Photosmart B110c\"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] prtMarkerColorantValue.1.1 = \"black ink\"
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] ATTR: marker-colors=none,none,none,none
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] ATTR: marker-names=\'\"black ink\"\',\'\"yellow ink\"\',\'\"cyan ink\"\',\'\"magenta ink\"\'
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] ATTR: marker-types=ink,ink,ink,ink
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] ATTR: marker-levels=15,58,0,0
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] new_supply_state=8, change_state=ffff
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -developer-low-report
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -developer-empty-warning
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -marker-supply-low-report
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: +marker-supply-empty-warning
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -opc-near-eol-report
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -opc-life-over-warning
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -toner-low-report
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -toner-empty-warning
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -waste-receptacle-almost-full-report
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -waste-receptacle-full-warning
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -cleaner-life-almost-over-report
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -cleaner-life-over-warning
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] File contains 1 pages
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Starting renderer with command: gs -dShowAcroForm  -q -dBATCH -dPARANOIDSAFER -dQUIET -dNOPAUSE -dNOMEDIAATTRS -dNOINTERPOLATE -r300x300 -sDEVICE=pjxl300 -dBitsPerPixel=1 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=595 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=842 -dPrintQuality=0 -dRenderType=0 -sOutputFile=-   /tmp/foomatic-KskjrT 
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Starting process \"kid3\" (generation 1)
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Starting process \"kid4\" (generation 2)
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Starting process \"renderer\" (generation 2)
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] JCL: \033%-12345X@PJL
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] <job data> 
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] new_state=0, change_state=ffff
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -media-empty-warning
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -door-open-report
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -media-jam-warning
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -input-tray-missing-warning
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -output-tray-missing-warning
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -marker-supply-missing-warning
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -output-area-almost-full-report
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -output-area-full-warning
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] backendWaitLoop(snmp_fd=5, addr=0x558cec64a9c8, side_cb=0x558ceb2586a0)
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] renderer exited with status 255
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Connecting to 192.168.0.99:9100
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Kid3 exit status: 3
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] PID 33680 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/foomatic-rip) stopped with status 9.
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Connecting to printer.
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Connected to printer.
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Connected to 192.168.0.99:9100...
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] backendRunLoop(print_fd=0, device_fd=6, snmp_fd=5, addr=0x558cec64a9c8, use_bc=1, side_cb=0x558ceb2586a0)
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] STATE: +cups-waiting-for-job-completed
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] Waiting for printer to finish.
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.1 = 94
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.2 = 0
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.3 = 0
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.4 = 0
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] ATTR: marker-levels=66,0,0,0
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] new_supply_state=8, change_state=0
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] new_state=0, change_state=0
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] PAGE: total 1
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] PID 33681 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/socket) exited with no errors.
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] End of messages
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] printer-state=3(idle)
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] printer-state-message="Waiting for printer to finish."
D [21/Dec/2021:11:59:25 +0100] [Job 496] printer-state-reasons=marker-supply-empty-warning
```

I tried apt-purge: cups, ghostscript and reinstall them. Didn't help.
I tried:

```
sudo rmdir /usr/share/ghostscript/9.25/iccprofiles
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgs9-common
```

Didn't help.

Printer:HP photosmart B110 connected through WIFI.
System: Ubuntu 20.04, all updates.
From Windows or from Android printer prints well.

Comment: have you tried to set a valid paper size format previous to send a print job?.

Comment: Yes, there is it. A4 paper. Does not work even If I click to print test page from Printer settings in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I tried to change the driver from automatic: HP PhotoSmart P100 to HP PhotoSmart P1000. It was only try, but It works..

Comment: You could use my [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382655/canon-ip7210-drivers-installation/1382656#1382656) for install drivers on 20.04 too. Just use your printer driver and follow these steps.