# Printer no longer works after Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

After updating to Ubuntu 20.04, I found that my printer doesn't work anymore. So I removed and re-added it. But then it simply installs a "Generic Text-Only Printer" which, not only does it not print, it doesn't even receive print jobs at all. I've tried this with both my Canon iP2770 and a Canon E410.

Answer (score 9):

I have found a solution here:

> [Install printer Canon MP280 on ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1241123/66093)

Basically, I have to issue this command in Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-gutenprint
```

And then try re-adding the printer again.

Comment: I had the same with a clean minimal installation of Ubuntu 22.04 and your solution works. Thanks.