# Linux drivers for Canon PIXMA MP180 inkjet printer

Tags: drivers, canon

**Linux Version**: 20.04.2 LTS

**Machine**: Dell Inspiron 15 / 5000 Series.

I would like to get a Linux driver for a Canon PIXMA MP180 printer.

This printer was shipped ~ 2008 with just Windows XP and MacOS drivers. No Linux support existed from the manufacturer then.

In the meantime I see that Canon have drivers for some Canon printers in the MP series but this starts at the MP230 series.

[This webpage](https://www.openprinting.org/printer/Canon/Canon-MULTIPASS-MP180) mentions some drivers that run on the Canon MP180. But when I download and try to install the most suitable ones, i.e.  5.2.7 (DEB for LSB 3.2) or 5.0.1 (DEB for LSB 3.1) the installation seizes on "pending" state.

I must admit that I am a bit confused by the CUPS project and how exactly it provides an alternative to proprietary drivers for specific operating systems.

Likewise with the Gutenprint project which as a long listing of "experimental" drivers.

Can anyone provide a link to installation of these drivers, as the "How To Install" link leads nowhere ?

Comment: @Rinzwind  This won't work as attempts to add the repo links gives an error about release versions. Checking online this means that stuff made fro Ubuntu 14 won't run on Ubuntu 20.04. Let's forget it for a while.

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/a/1241123/15811  That works in 22.04 for an MP270. MP280 is a modified MP270  so  that should work.Try that one :)

Comment: Mine is an **MP180 - not MP280 !** As stated in OP, Canon themselves have Linux drivers for every printer from MP230 series onwards. https://www.canon.ie/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mp_series/pixma_mp230.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit)

Comment: Given up on it and handed it away to someone with Windows 8. In fairness, Canon *does have* drivers for MP and other printers from about 2012 onwards - so it's not an enforcing scrappage plan by the manufacturer.